# Is there a Typescript equivalant to Java/.NET Reflection? OR - How can I get a list of classes that extend a given abstract class?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, reflection, npm

Call me Noah.

```
// AnimalsBase: a package installed via 'npm install animals-base'
export default abstract class Animal {...}
```

There's this abstract base class, `Animal`, defined in an `npm` package, which gets extended by other packages:

```
// earth - I know about it because of 'npm install animals-earth'
import Animal from 'creatures-base'

export class Human extends Animal {...}
export class Cat extends Animal {...}
export class Dog extends Animal {...}
...
```

As you may know, **I need to gather up collections that include every type of animal at *runtime***. Thing is, I'm never sure what planet I'll be working on any given day:

```
// tatooine - installed via 'npm install animals-tatooine'
import Animal from 'creatures-base'

export class WampRat extends Animal {...}
export class Bantha extends Animal {...}
export class SandPerson extends Animal {...}
...
```

I might even be expected to work several different planets on a given shift (deployment)...

## Question One:

Can this function be written?

```
function animalCollection() : [Animal] {
    return [ /* An array containing one of each type of animal */ ]
}
```

## Question Two:

If the above is possible, can I go further and discern the home planets of each animal?

```
function animalCollection(planet) : [Animal] {
    return [ /* An array containing one of each type of animal native to 'planet' */ ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [metadata reflection API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata).

I strongly recommend you to go through the de-facto standard article about decorators: [Decorators & metadata reflection in TypeScript](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript).

And there for you will find especially interesting this [part #4](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4).

Comment: This is helpful, but I find myself down a rabbit hole and I feel further from my destination than when I started. In particular, none of this documentation includes links to projects that can be downloaded and examined in their entirety. Can anyone point me toward a small project that uses these features?